# React-router-dom. Как вывести нужный элемент по маршруту

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

В v6 react-router-dom вместо

```
<Route path='/' component={App} />
```

От нас ожидают это

```
<Route path='/' element={<App />} />
```

Вопрос: я с помощью функции `map` пытаюсь вытащить маршруты из массива:

```
[{exact: true, component: App, path='/'}]
```

Но не понимаю как в v6 правильно передать компонент.

Код ниже не работает т.к. `component` в v6 заменен на element, но я не могу тут указать тот самый `<App />` мне нужно просто передать `App`

```
routes.map(route=>{
  return <Route 
    exact={route.exact}
    path={route.path}
    component={route.component}
      />
})
```

Пробовал так же `render` и `children` тоже не работают. Полагаю нужно указать что то типа `React.element(App)` но я не знаю точно как

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ. Создаём переменную в каждой итерации и передаем как компонент в треугольных скобках

```
routes.map(route=>{
let Component = route.component
  return <Route 
    exact={route.exact}
    path={route.path}
    element={<Component />}
      />
})
```

Comment: Дополнительно задался вопросом как повторить подобное в TypeScript. Там компилятор говорит, что Component  не может быть использован как JSX компонент

Comment: Кажется что с TypeScript в V6 react-router-dom эффективнее всего использовать готовый хук useRoutes